# How do I inject a Spring bean into Apache Wink?

Tags: spring, jpa, jax-rs, apache-wink

How do I inject Spring-managed beans into Apache Wink?

I have a wink application started in `web.xml` that starts fine if I stub out a dummy data service `@Autowired` under an interface within it. I have implemented a JPA service to provide the data implementing the same interface, set up via Spring 2.5.6. This works fine in isolation too.

I think I just need to inject my JPA service instead of my dummy service, but I can't figure out how to do that - tried `@Service` annotations and `<context:annotation-driven>`; tried manually injecting the JPA service. It's like Wink and Spring aren't aware of each other.

The [Wink docs do mention a Spring integration](https://cwiki.apache.org/WINK/55-spring-integration.html) , however this talks about an "Apache Wink core context file" which I can't find mention of elsewhere in the Wink docs.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Apache Wink core context file" `wink-core-context.xml` is a Spring configuration file.
It is part of "wink-spring-support".

You can find the file within `apache-wink-1.1.3-incubating-src.zip` in `apache-wink-1.1.3-incubating-src\wink-spring-support\src\main\resources\META-INF\server`

Comment: Cheers pal, hadn't realised that it was a separate library. Palm and face contact imminent.