# REST service not being registered in Apache wink with Spring and Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, apache-wink, apache-wink-spring

I have a Maven project with the dependencies listed below:

[image]

wink.version = 1.1.3-incubating and spring.version = 3.0.5.RELEASE

Application Context in Spring includes:

```
    <bean class="org.apache.wink.spring.Registrar">
    <property name="classes">
        <set value-type="java.lang.Class">
        </set>
    </property>
    <property name="instances">
        <set>
            <ref local="restexample" />
        </set>
    </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="restexample" class="com.example.rest.ExampleRest"></bean>
```

web.xml includes:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:META-INF/wink/wink-core-context.xml
        classpath:applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>restServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>restServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Rest Java Class includes:

```
@Path("/ex")
public class ExampleRest {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String example() throws IOException {
        return "{ 'id':'test' }";
    }
}
```

---

Looking at the logs I don't see any exception or problem, the 'restexample' bean is being created but... I get a **404** when I try to call the REST service.

I think **ExampleRest** is not being registered by Apache Wink.

Any idea ?

**UPDATE 02/14**:
Loking at the logs, I noticed that ExampleRest is not being registered by Apache Wink. Maybe, the problem is within the beans declaration or maybe the dependencies that I'm using.
I also set-up another project without spring and it works there. I really need Spring to use his IoD for daos and services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your web.xml, you point to a file called *wink-core-context.xml*. The path to this file seems wrong. It should be:

> META-INF/server/wink-core-context.xml

[See source](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/wink/tags/wink-1.1.3-incubating/wink-spring-support/src/main/resources/META-INF/server/wink-core-context.xml)

Not sure why you don't see the FileNotFoundException here.

Comment: just found a similar answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182329/beans-injected-into-apache-wink-with-spring-arent-registered